# Colorgcc in combination with catkin_make to colorize compiler output

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I was trying to colorize the compiler output of catkin_make. I tried using colorgcc.
As per the manual I created symlinks to c++, g++, gcc, and cc to point to colorgcc and added the directory to the PATH. When compiling without catkin_make the colorization works, with catkin_make it does not.

Any help getting this to work is much appreciated.

Kind regards,

Okke Hendriks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/167336/colorgcc-in-combination-with-catkin_make-to-colorize-compiler-output/) by [Okke](https://answers.ros.org/users/7721/okke/) on ROS Answers with karma: 131 on 2014-05-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It should work. Did you do this for a new workspace? Otherwise, you might need to make clean once as cmake stores the compiler path.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-05-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1